# Unix script stalls/freezing on loop for some odd reason?

Tags: loops, unix

```
while read FILE;
do

echo "$FILE"

done
```

Pretty trivial code... but I have no idea what could possibly be messing it up...I've looked everywhere at this seems to be correct...

Did added quotations but no luck-

I'm trying to read every file in the directory
- tried adding " in $*;" to the end of the first line with no luck

So is there a way to iterate through all the files and pipe each one to read?

Ok and is there a way for it to iterate through ONLY files and not directories?

Comment: What input are you giving it? You should likely put `echo "$FILE"` instead of just `echo $FILE`. Remember the contents of `$FILE` will replace the variable and *then* the command is executed.

Comment: `read` doesn't read files automatically. It reads from STDIN unless redirected.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it doesn't freeze up. It simply waits for input. That's what `read FILE` is supposed to do: read a line from standard input (=terminal unless a redirection is present) and store it in the `FILE` variable.

BTW, there's an extra semicolon you might want to remove; or did you perhaps mean to write

```
while read FILE; do
  echo $FILE
done
```

If you meant to iterate over every file in a directory, use

```
for file in *; do
  echo "<$file>"
done
```

If you meant to iterate over the arguments given to your script, use

```
for arg in "$@"; do
  echo "<$arg>"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should likely put echo "$FILE" instead of just echo $FILE. Remember the contents of $FILE will replace the variable and then the command is executed.

For example, if you have just:

```
echo $FILE
```

but the value of file is `hello; shutdown`, you could be in for a world of hurt. :)